# C# SQLite delete does not work

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have this helper function:

```
public bool Delete(String tableName, String where)
    {
        Boolean returnCode = true;
        try
        {
            this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("delete from {0} where {1};", tableName, where));                
        }
        catch (Exception fail)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fail.Message);
            returnCode = false;
        }
        return returnCode;
    }
```

TableName contains "[MyTable]"
and where contains "[MyTable ID]='4ffbd580-b17d-4731-b162-ede8d698e026'" which is a unique guid representing the row ID.

The function returns true, like it was successful, and no exception, but the rows are not deleted from DB, what's wong?

This is the ExecuteNonQuery function

```
 public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
    {
        SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
        cnn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
        mycommand.CommandText = sql;
        int rowsUpdated = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();
        return rowsUpdated;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't just embed SQL like that. You should use *parameterized* SQL, to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Next, you should look at the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery`. Assuming it follows the *normal* pattern of `ExecuteNonQuery`, it should return the number of rows affected. I suspect it's returning 0, which will mean that nothing's matching your `where` clause.

(I'd also stop catching `Exception` - probably stop catching *anything*, but at least catch something specific if you must. I'd get rid of the local variable, too, and just return directly when you know what you want to return...)

Comment: I don't use SQLite on a webserver, this is a Windows application

Comment: Yes the ExecuteNonQuery returns 0 as the rows affected, by why? The ID of the row is a GUID type, not string

Comment: Also, at least break out the (horrible) concatenation of the SQL query into its own variable so you can inspect the query before sending it to the database. You can paste the same query into any SQLite database browser (the Firefox add-on is quite good). This should make it obvious what's going on.

Comment: I have pasted the query in SQLite Database browser 2.0 and executed it. The return message is No Error and again no row was deleted.

Comment: It seems that it cannot find the guid type column from my string

Comment: Is there a specific way of addressing GUID type columns in sqlite ?

Comment: @MarioM: This is one place where using parameterized SQL may well help you: you can pass in an actual Guid value, instead of a string... read more about parameterized SQL.

Comment: I've got the same problem, you'll need to call Guid.ToString() - this helped me: **command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id.ToString());**

Comment: @Sven: Is that because SQLite *doesn't* support GUID columns directly? I would avoid the string conversion if possible.

Comment: @Jon Yes alright, SQLite only supports some basic string and integer data types, have a look here: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html